# Best printer for greeting cards that won't fade?

Tags: print-design, hardware-recommendation

I'm so stuck and can't find an answer anywhere!

Which printer is the best for printing greeting cards and stationery? I don't want to outsource as I'd like full control over colours, fonts etc. So a home printer that will ensure that my graphics don't fade.

I print onto a thick, matte, slightly textured paper.

Thank you!

Comment: Many photographers use high-end Epson printers.

Comment: Please reference the link above your question.  If the answer to that question doesn't help you please make an edit to this question on why.

Comment: Depending on how many/much printing you require you may find your best results are with a professional printer - a home printer will cost you alot to run with those toner cartridges after a while, a professional printers will have a very stable environment and workflow so that each print run is consistent and will be able to work with a range of materials depending on whether digital print or offset. Just find a printer that will suit your output requirements. I have a great one opposite that can do both digi and offset and does small runs.

Comment: This question shouldn't be considered duplicate :( There are so many details that cannot be covered on the post you answered to, Darth; and responding to question like this one here on the other one seems out of context. A bit disappointing how all these printers questions are all redirected to your answer...!